# What does "mortal bodies" in Romans 8:11 mean?

Tags: romans

What does "mortal bodies" in [Romans 8:11](https://biblehub.com/romans/8-11.htm) mean?

> The Spirit of God, who raised Jesus from the dead, lives in you. And just as God raised Christ Jesus from the dead, he will give life to your **mortal bodies** by this same Spirit living within you.

Does it mean the dead body after we die? Or our present living body which will die?

Comment: Really needs to be read in the context of the previous verse.  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/romans-811-present-or-future is related

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

Indeed, this verse is speaking of our present mortal (mortal = subject to death) bodies.  Our mortal body (which is dead because of sin) is **subject to death**....meaning we have not died yet but most definitely will.

Our present mortal bodies are dead because of sin….but the Spirit is life because of righteousness.

It is through the Spirit that we must deaden sin in order for life to be given to our present mortal (subject to death) bodies though.

We must always sow to the Spirit and not live after the flesh in order to reap that life.

> *Romans 8:10-13 KJV (10)  And if Christ be in you, the body is dead because of sin; **but the Spirit is life because of righteousness**.*

Jesus  was dead and is alive now and so His life is to be made manifest in our mortal bodies  **now** by the same Spirit that dwells in us.  Jesus is risen.  Jesus is alive.

> *(11)  But if the Spirit of him that raised up Jesus from the dead dwell in you, he that raised up Christ from the dead **shall also
>   quicken your mortal bodies by his Spirit** that dwelleth in you. (12) 
>   Therefore, brethren, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live after
>   the flesh.*

It is through the Spirit that dwells in us that we must use to mortify (deaden/kill) the deeds of the body so that we may have life (the quickening life of Jesus)in this present mortal body.  Sin must not rule over us.

Even if we have the Spirit within us and yet continue to live after the flesh, we shall die as the Spirit of God will not always strive with people who continue to live after the flesh.  The wages of  (the) sin is death.  But our God is patient not willing that any should perish.  His patience is our salvation.

> *(13)  **For if ye live after the flesh, ye shall die:** **but if ye through the Spirit do mortify the deeds of the body, ye shall live**.*

The same Word (Saying) of God spoken in Genesis 6:3 still applies today as His Spirit will not always strive with man who is also flesh….that is,  striving with men who continue to live after the flesh (behaving in envy, strife, wrath, hatred, etc).

If we continue to live after the flesh, we shall die even if we have His Spirit dwelling within us as the Spirit of God will not always strive with those who do. We grieve the Spirit of God that dwells within us when we continue to live after the flesh.  If we continue to live after the flesh, we shall die.

> *Genesis 6:3 KJV (3)  And the LORD said, **My spirit shall not always strive with man, for that he also is flesh:** yet his days shall be an
>   hundred and twenty years.*
>
> *Genesis 6:5-6 KJV (5)  And GOD saw that the wickedness of man was
>   great in the earth, and that every imagination of the thoughts of his
>   heart was only evil continually. (6)  **And it repented the LORD that he
>   had made man on the earth, and it grieved him at his heart**.*

The Spirit of God strives within those people who continue to live after flesh as the Spirit and the flesh are contrary to one another.  They are opposite to one another and there is a struggle if one continues to live after the flesh and not after the Spirit.

Having His Spirit dwelling within us is no guarantee of life being given to our mortal bodies. We must **through His Spirit deaden the deeds of the body** so that the Spirit may quicken our present bodies.

> *Galatians 5:16-26 KJV (16)  This I say then, Walk in the Spirit, and ye shall not fulfil the lust of the flesh. (17)  **For the flesh lusteth
>   against the Spirit, and the Spirit against the flesh: and these are
>   contrary the one to the other**: so that ye cannot do the things that ye
>   would. (18)  But if ye be led of the Spirit, ye are not under the
>   law*.

The works of the flesh are these:

> *(19)  **Now the works of the flesh are manifest, which are these; Adultery, fornication, uncleanness, lasciviousness, (20)  Idolatry,
>   witchcraft, hatred, variance, emulations, wrath, strife, seditions,
>   heresies, (21)  Envyings, murders, drunkenness, revellings,** and such
>   like: of the which I tell you before, as I have also told you in time
>   past, that they which do such things shall not inherit the kingdom of
>   God.*

But the fruit of the Spirit are these:

> *(22)  **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith, (23)  Meekness, temperance:** against such
>   there is no law.*

They that are Christ’s have crucified the flesh (see the works of the flesh list Galatians 5) with the affections and the lusts. The Spirit of God does not strive with those who (through His Spirit) have deadened the works of the flesh in their mortal bodies.

> *(24)  A**nd they that are Christ's have crucified the flesh with the affections and lusts.***

If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk (a continuous activity) in the Spirit.  That walk is on the narrow way that leads to life.   Those who are led by the Spirit are the sons of God.   There is now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit (see Romans 8:1).

> *(25)  **If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk in the Spirit.** (26)  Let us not be desirous of vain glory, provoking one another, envying
>   one another.*

We are to always bear about in the mortal body the dying of the Lord Jesus (we keep His death by dying to sin always) so that the life of Jesus also might made manifest (shine) in our body. Jesus is alive now so that His life shall be manifest in this present mortal body that we are living in.

> *2 Corinthians 4:10-11 KJV (10)  Always bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus, **that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our body***

The life of Jesus shall be made manifest in our mortal (which is subject to death) flesh if we always keep His death in our mortal bodies. Jesus is risen now so that we might have life now in this present body.  As He lives now, we shall live also. 
.

> *(11)  For we which live are alway delivered unto death for Jesus' sake, **that the life also of Jesus might be made manifest in our mortal
>   flesh**.*

Our old man is crucified with Him so that the body of sin might be destroyed so that we may live with Him.  We should NOT then serve sin any longer.

He gives us the power to become the sons of God as we use the Spirit to destroy the body of sin from our lives.  The continuous living/walking after the Spirit gives our present mortal body His life which we shall reap in due season if we do not become faint in well doing (sowing after the Spirit).

> *Romans 6:6-9 KJV (6)  Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with him, **that the body of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we
>   should not serve sin.** (7)  For he that is dead is freed from sin. (8) 
>   **Now if we be dead with Christ, we believe that we shall also live with
>   him:** (9)  Knowing that Christ being raised from the dead dieth no
>   more; death hath no more dominion over him.*

Thanks for reading and considering.

Answer (score 0):

Siju George,

In this verse, he is speaking *operationally*, so from this understanding, it implies that Paul is referring to our *present living body* that we reside in *right now*.

I suppose the way that the verse could be read, in essence, is like this:

> But if [since] the Spirit of him that raised up Jesus from the dead
>   [continuously] dwells in you, he that raised up Christ from the dead
>   shall also quicken your mortal bodies by his Spirit [who] that
>   indwells [take residence in] in you.

This is operational "in the now." It is the Holy Spirit that raised Yeshua from the dead, and Paul tells us the same: that we also need a 'resurrection life', and he is speaking as if to say: "...right now..."

If you're looking at the King James Version, there are conditional clauses for the word "if..." in the Greek, as following:

1. If and it’s so; “since, indeed,”
2. If and it’s not so; If: maybe it’s so and maybe it’s not;
3. If: I wished it was so but probably not;
4. “If”: First class conditional = “Since.” “indwells” (dwelleth) = take up residence in (present tense, continuous process).

Have a gander at Romans 7:24, as well, where Paul says so identifiably:

> “O wretched man that I am! who shall deliver me from the body of this
>   death?”

Interesting that the word "wretched" denotes or means that it's a "struggle." As long as we are in our current, temporal bodies, there is going to be a struggle in this life, as we all can identify as Christians. This "body of death" is a perfect description. The Body will continue on sinning, but the Holy Spirit indwelling us helps us by acting 'operationally', and that same Holy Spirit that raised Christ from the dead is the same Holy Spirit currently residing within each born-again believer that will 'resurrect' us, as well, and already has, in essence, since we're now "dead to sin," etc. God looks at us, positionally, as being 'dead to sin', but our mortal bodies will go on sinning, even though we as Christian don't want it to, but it will until we receive our 'glorified bodies'.

Answer (score 0):

### What does "mortal bodies" in Romans 8:11 mean?

**1 Cor 15 39-49 NKJV**

> 39 All flesh is not the same flesh, but there is one kind of flesh of men, another flesh of animals, another of fish, and another of birds.
>
> 40 There are also celestial bodies and terrestrial bodies; but the glory of the celestial is one, and the glory of the terrestrial is another. 41 There is one glory of the sun, another glory of the moon, and another glory of the stars; for one star differs from another star in glory.
>
> 42 So also is the resurrection of the dead. The body is sown in corruption, it is raised in incorruption. 43 It is sown in dishonor, it is raised in glory. It is sown in weakness, it is raised in power. 44 It is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. There is a natural body, and there is a spiritual body. 45 And so it is written, “The first man Adam became a living being.” The last Adam became a life-giving spirit.
>
> 46 However, the spiritual is not first, but the natural, and afterward the spiritual. 47 The first man was of the earth, made of dust; the second Man is the Lord from heaven. 48 As was the man of dust, so also are those who are made of dust; and as is the heavenly Man, so also are those who are heavenly. 49 And as we have borne the image of the man of dust, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly Man.

### Conclusion

The **image of the man of dust**, but the incorruptible body **the image of the heavenly Man**.

### The Hope

**1 Cor 15:51-52 NKJV**

> 51 Behold, I tell you a mystery: We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed— 52 in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.